# how to deploy a play 2.4.x framework web application in tomcat?

Tags: playframework-2.4

Appreciate if anyone can point to any resources that describes the steps to build a war for play 2.4.x framework and can be deployed to tomcat 7 or 8. I saw play2war plugin. I am not sure if this will work. Are there any other way to build a war and deploy to tomcat 7/8? Ultimately, I need to deploy it to aws elasticbeanstalk.

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Your best bet would be to use Docker for deploying a Play Framework app to AWS elasticbeanstalk.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html